# I have used djangorest to create an api but when i make a post request it returns an error saying 400 BAD request

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

model :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    publicationDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.publicationDate = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is the serializer :

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post.objects.create(
            author=validated_data["author"], title=validated_data["title"], text=validated_data["text"]
        )
        post.save()
        return post

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["author", "title", "text", "pk", 'publicationDate']
```

this is the api view :

```
class PostList(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and this is the request I`m making :

```
axios.post('/api/posts/', form, {
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
            .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

this is the error it returns
"POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/ 400 (Bad Request)"

I have been at this problem for days now and i have tried everything but it just wont work

Comment: Can you share the exact error logs here?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: What is error in python? Actually 400 happens because of missing parameters. So also add that error log in question.

Comment: settle.js:19 
 Uncaught (in promise) 
mt {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Comment: check if it's working in postman?

Comment: Bad Request: /api/posts/
[01/Dec/2022 09:33:52] "POST /api/posts/ HTTP/1.1" 400 63

Comment: the last one is the error in python

Comment: this might help you :-- https://blog.logrocket.com/django-rest-framework-create-api/

Comment: I think the api should be working fine cause the get requests are all working no problem

Comment: try blog mentioned above. This will solve your probelm